# Custom converter class not being found after JDK update

Tags: java, apache-axis

I'm using Axis2 (v1.7.4) with a custom converter class. I was able to deploy it and everything was working fine.

My machine had its JDK and JRE updated via a GPO update and it no longer finds the converter class. I get  the following: "Can not load the converter util class [CLASSNAME] using default org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.ConverterUtil class". I've confirmed that the class is in my jar file.

I'm using Netbeans with Ant, if that makes a difference.

I've tried recompiling on different machines. I've also tried downgrading the JDK version, but can only go down one version.